# Button to filter out legal work authorizations requirement

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I am using the Careers website everyday. I am however quite unhappy about the fact that most of job offers "allowing remote work" are also asking for a work permit, especially if the company is a US based company.

So let's present that as a feature request... Could we have a button to filter out legal work authorizations requirements?

Comment: This could be a check button, "remote work abroad"

Comment: Just limit the search in your country. working for a company from a different country almost surely requires legal work anyway, so just don't search for them at all.

Comment: Most countries require a RTW (Right To Work) permit, even if you're working from abroad. Not doing so is illegal.

Comment: @Bakuriu I want to work in projects for any company/country, remotely. It is not a country issue.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ You can also work as a self employed/independant/service provider. You don't need to be employed directly.

Comment: @Sebas my point is that working for a company that isn't in your country requires legal paperwork *even if you work remotely*. So if you don't want to do legal paperwork your *only* option is to search in your own country.

Comment: @Bakuriu read my answer to ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ's comment. Working for a company does not mean being hired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Our current policy is that "remote work" should imply from anywhere in the world. Please flag any listing you have an issue with and we'll review them.

If they say in the listing they require legal right to work in x country, we usually remove the remote work flag. Now, if they toggle remote work, but are requiring right to work late in the interview process but do not mention it in the listing, there's not much we can do about that.

Comment: Perhaps employers are shying away from remote work abroad because of the fact that a remote worker abroad will almost always have to act as a freelancer/contractor, not a regular employee.

Comment: Oh, I get it, thank you